# Run cron from specific directory and log time in log file

Tags: bash, shell, logging, cron

I have this script that parses images from an external address. 
I need to make sure that the script is running in a specific directory. I also want to log the time.

This is what I have done for the cronjob:

`*/2 * * * * cd /path/to/script; (time /path/to/script/code.sh arg) &>> /path/to/log/time.log)`

And my shell script is pretty simple:

```
#!/bin/sh
timestamp()
{
    date +"%Y-%m-%d %T"
}
echo "###########################"
echo $(timestamp)
python /path/to/script/parser1.py "-s$1"
python /path/to/script/parser2.py "-s$1"
```

I get mail to my user, but it is just of the $(timestamp) echo. I should have the timestamp and also have output from both parser1 and parser2 updating in my time.log file. I don't know why this isn't working! I can run the cronjob command from the command line and it works.

Comment: Don't you have any debug output from your `*.py` files? Could you insert some prints right at the beginning of `parser*` files?

Comment: If you insert a `echo $(type python)` right after `echo $(timestamp)` in your shell script, what do you get?

Comment: I do have debug output for my python files. Well, I have debug output that appears when run from command line. It's just that it isn't being put in the log file when I run it from the cronjob. And that echo returns "python is /usr/bin/python"

Comment: Ok, now If you insert a echo $(pwd) right after echo $(timestamp) in your shell script, what do you see?

Comment: I get the correct directory.

Comment: Is this `correct direcory` the same with your working directory when you call your python scripts manually with no issues?

Comment: I believe so, yes. The only problem may be that the directory it prints looks like this `/path/to/script` whereas when I run it, it would be `/path/to/script/`

Comment: If still struggling, my suggestion is to compare the whole set of environment variables seen in the `code.sh` *versus* your normal environment. This can be done by inserting a `echo $(env)` in your shell script and then calling `env` manually in the terminal. The comparison should help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I think the problem is that `cron` is running your script, but not from the directory you want to run it FROM.  I am not sure, but I believe `cron` executes scripts from either the `/root` or `/` directories.

Try this - Add this right below your timestamp function - modified with the proper path, of course.

```
DIRNAME=/path/to/directory
LOGFILE=logfile.log
cd ${DIRNAME}
echo $(timestamp) >> ${LOGFILE}
```

And then remove the current `echo $(timestamp)` line.

Also, make sure the log file exists, and you have write access to the file.

Comment: According to the OP's code sample, the `*.py` files are called with absolute path. Are you sure the `cron` current working directory is still important?

Comment: Thank you for your help! The file exists and I do have write access. When I try to run the shell script with your modifications, I do not get any output to the log. This is part of the output upon running the shell: 
`./shell.sh: 10: ./shell.sh: [[: not found`

Comment: Then drop the test.  It just checks to verify the file exists.  See modified code.  @chatraed - no, I'm not sure - good point for discussion.  I do believe, though, that the working directory is relevant, if the python script does not specify absolute paths internally.  (i.e., you might want to run a python script from your working directory by calling a python script from another directory)

Comment: @ice13berg: I agree that the python scripts could rely on the fact that they are called from a specific path (generally the one they are stored in).

Comment: @ice13berg I made that change and it behaves the same as the mail file, it only prints the timestamp in the log. Which is good! I should have been more clear in my original question. What I need in the log file is that timestamp, the output from my python script, and the total time it took for script completion. Can I track the time that it takes for a script to run from a shell script? I could probably just cat the output of that and my python scripts.

Comment: Okay well thank you! I used this to log everything I want.